# Error while submitting my google action assistant app to release

Tags: action, dialogflow-es

I am trying to submit my google action to alpha release. Its throwing 500 error. No idea what to do. All the mandatory information is filled up.

dialogflow app is created and integrated with google home. A version is created and published in dialogflow. Now while trying to publish in google assistant alpha, its not getting through.

Comment: follow these guidelines in the link to submit your action :- https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/submit

Comment: Can you provide more details please?